# I simplified a part of my project to solve this specific problem I have (invalid write of size 4/segmentation fault)

Tags: segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

A step by step compiler says "Invalid write of size 4", while in general it's a segmentation fault. I don't understand how to solve this. I have been fidgeting with this for the past few hours. What am I missing?

```
typedef struct Person{
  int age;
  char name[6]
} Person;

fun(Person **parray){
  *parray = realloc(*parray, 6 * (sizeof(Person)));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
      strcpy (parray[i]->name, "John");
      parray[i]->age = 15;
    }
}

int main() {
  Person *parray;
  
  parray = calloc(0, sizeof(Person));
  
  fun(&parray);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand how to solve this.

The first step should be to enable compiler warnings, and fix all the bugs the compiler tells you about. If you are using `gcc`, turn on `-Wall -Wextra` flags.

Now, the bug is in that `parray[i]` inside `fun()` is not the correct expression -- it treats `parray` as pointer to an array, when in fact `parray` points to a *single* variable (of the same name) in `main()`.

You can fix this by using the correct expression: `(*parray)[i]`.

A better fix is to avoid the double pointer altogether, e.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Person{
  int age;
  char name[6]
} Person;

Person *fun(Person *parray){
  Person *result = realloc(parray, 6 * (sizeof(Person)));
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
    strcpy(result[i].name, "John");
    result[i].age = 15;
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  Person *parray = calloc(0, sizeof(Person));
  parray = fun(parray);

  free(parray);
  return 0;
}
```

If you insist on passing a double-pointer into `fun()` and updating it inside, you can do that, while still minimizing the use of the double-pointer, like so:

```
void fun(Person **parray){
  Person *p = *parray = realloc(*parray, 6 * (sizeof(Person)));
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
    strcpy(p[i].name, "John");
    p[i].age = 15;
  }
}
```